# How to find people "similar to" another person in twitter

Tags: twitter

How can one find people in twitter who are similar to some known person(in terms of work/company/whatever)
for example twitter gives this 
https://twitter.com/#!/similar_to/brianmadden

can anyone please suggest some api to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Twitter expose that particular bit of functionality in their API. You can see all of the supported methods [on the Twitter API documentation site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api).

Comment: Yeah I have checked twitter api, there is no such method available. moreover I tried scrapping the content inside https://twitter.com/#!/similar_to/brianmadden using python library(or file_get_content), But the content is very different than  the original content that we see while clicking the URL. Any suggestion

Comment: If we could get the original content inside the url, then we easily regex for the necessary result